# Boot Linux to unbootable drive (move /bin, /usr/bin, /var, /opt to non-boot drive)/load Linux from a different drive

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot, mount

Setting:

- a Supermicro motherboard that implements EFI bootorder incorrectly, overwriting it at every boot. `efibootmgr` changes only persist if I set `bootnext`, not if I set `bootorder`.
- a PCIe-connected NVMe drive that the Supermicro motherboard refuses to set as a bootable drive
- an existing Linux installation on HDD RAID1

Goal: get the Linux installation's root filesystem moved to the NVMe drive and bootable.

Problem: If I simply copy the system to the NVMe drive, I cannot boot from it because of motherboard limitation. If I copy /bin to the NVMe drive and change the mount point to that, I will end up with a system that cannot find the command `mount` (plus probably others).

Considered solutions:

- Modify the bootloader (grub2) to load the kernel from a different drive than where it is. Don't know how to address that drive or how to do that.
- Manage to move /bin, /usr/bin, /var, /opt, /etc to the NVMe drive and get them mounted at boot regardless of the missing `mount`. Do not know how to do it.

Solution: superuser.com.

Comment: With UEFI what matters is the location of the ESP

Comment: Thank you, but I was under the impression that the EFI system partition (ESP) does not contain the /bin but just the bootloader. And when it comes to this particular flavor of Supermicro motherboard (X10DAi), it does not implement the UEFI booting correctly. It will not boot from the NVMe drive through the Supermicro firmware settings, and it will not load any bootloader if I simply remove VD 0, which currently is the boot device, then install a fresh copy on the NVMe and reboot the computer.

Comment: Where's the ESP exactly? If on a bootable drive it shouldn't matter where the other partitions are.

Comment: The ESP is on drive 0. Drive 0 is a HDD unit. The system should be on an NVMe unit instead of a HDD. The NVMe unit cannot be booted. For the sake of clarity: the EFI partition is not on the NVMe unit. If you know how to instruct Grub 2 or the EFI system to chainload the boot loader from the NVMe unit, that will help greatly.

Comment: OK,  so first make sure you're booting in UEFI mode, then choose or create your partitions wherever you want but keep the ESP on the HDD and select your options accordingly. Grub should be installed in the ESP regardless of the location of all the other partitions.

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell me how I can tell the existing boot loader to continue from the NVMe unit instead of the HDD? The grub.cfg does not comment on what drive to use and the efi files are binary, making it not possible for me to edit them.

Comment: `get them mounted at boot regardless of the missing mount` solution: initramfs

Comment: Thank you. Would you like to elaborate a bit more?

Comment: AFAIR, you can boot from other physical device than your ESP is located on, so you can keep it on HDD, but move actual installation to NVMe... or is it what you are actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I was trying to move the installation to the NVMe and keep the bootloader on the spinner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Install a mock version of Fedora on the NVMe drive using a live flash disk and specify the existing bootloader disk as the location for bootloader; remember to specify that it is to be mounted
- Delete the mock version's /etc, /opt, /root, /share, /usr, and /var directories
- Copy the above directories from the old installation to the mock installation
- Adjust the mock installation's /etc/fstab to mount the NVMe partition as the root file system
- Adjust the grub.cfg file to default to item 0 instead of what the installer installed
- Reboot